# c++ boost::multi_array index too large

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I'm using a two-dimensional boost::multi_array to store objects of a custom struct. The problem is that I have a huge amount of these objects so that the index of the array I would need exceeds the range of an integer. Is there any possibility to use long as an index of a multi-array or do you have any other suggestions on how to store a dataset this big and still keep it accessible at a decent speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html) states that the index type is *unspecified*, but looking into the [repository](https://github.com/boostorg/multi_array/blob/develop/include/boost/multi_array/types.hpp), one sees that the definition most likely is `typedef std::ptrdiff_t index`;

So if you compile for an x86 32-bit system, you will surely run out of addressable memory anyways, so the limited size of indicies is not your real problem. Your only option would be to chose a system with enough memory, which has to be one with more than 2^32 bytes and thus has to be a 64 bit one. 2^64 will be certainly enough to represent the dimensions of your multiarray.